# Ito's chain rule and multidimensional derivation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

In the book "Quant Job Interview: Questions and Answers" by M. Joshi in the derivation of the final Black-Scholes formula he makes usage of Ito's chain rule. To get specific, he goes from
$$ dC (t, S_t) = \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t} r S_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_t^2} \sigma^2 S_t^2\right)dt  + \sigma S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t} dW_t$$ to
$$ d\left(\frac{C (t, S_t)}{B_t}  \right) = \frac{1}{B_t}\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t} r S_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_t^2} \sigma^2 S_t^2 - rC\right)dt  + \sigma \frac{S_t}{B_t} \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t} dW_t.$$
In his book he shortly claims he has achieved that by simply applying Ito's chain rule. I'm familiar with the standard case of Ito's Lemma, but I don't quite get which connection there is in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely what is called Ito's product rule or Leibniz rule; given two (one dimensional) Ito processes
$$
dX_t=\mu_{1,\,t}dt+\sigma_{1,\,t}dW_t
$$
and
$$
dY_t=\mu_{1,\,t}dt+\sigma_{1,\,t}dW_t,
$$
the differential of their product is
$$
d(XY)=XdY+YdX+dXdY.
$$

In your case, you can do the computations considering that, by differencing $f(B_t)=\frac{1}{B_t}=e^{-rt}$
$$
d\frac{1}{B_t}=f_tdt=-re^{-rt}dt=-r\frac{1}{B_t}dt.
$$

Comment: How did you get from $dB_t = r B_t d_t$ to the inverse formulation? Other than that, it does the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: you use Ito-Doeblin formula on $\frac{1}{B_t}=e^{-rt}$

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: From the trivial differential equation exponential approach, it seems clear that if $dB_t = r B_t d_t$, then $B_t = e^{rt}$. If you invert it, of course $\frac{1}{B_t} = e^{-rt}$. If we then take the derivative of $\frac{1}{B_t}$, we of course get to $-r e^{-rt} dt$. But where do we need Ito-Doeblin here? Is it mathematically correct to treat the stochastic process with the means of standard calculus here?

Comment: $B_t$ in this setting is not stochastic, because there is nothing random in it. The stochastic part is $C$ and for that we apply the Ito calculus, leading to the product rule in your original question

Comment: Thank you so much. But the Ito-Doeblin approach is not needed, then (?).

Comment: Not necessary on $B$, but when you have the differential of a product of a stochastic process $C$ and a non stochastic process $f(B)=B^{-1}$ (for example), Ito calculus s necessary because of the stochastic component.